# How to fileReplacements for angular library?

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-workspace-configuration

My goal is to replace `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts` of an Angular library.

The problem is a Angular library do not have `fileReplacements` key in the `angular.json` file. I need to replace `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts` when I do `npx ng build app1`.

Reference:

1. [Angular Workspace](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527)
2. [Angular application as a library](https://dev.to/michaeljota/how-to-split-an-angular-app-into-micro-frontend-apps-1fi9)